# is access to samba share dependent on internet access

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Running Ubuntu 7.04.
Samba is installed and running. Ubuntu server is connected to the internet thru an adsl modem.
Rest of the network consists of windows-xp machines

All xp machines can see the shared samba folders when internet access is on. If however , the internet access is interrupted , then the samba server cannot be viewed and no sharing occurs.

Is samba folder sharing dependent on internet access ?

Comment: No, it is not dependent on external connections at all. Can you describe your network and samba config details a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

> Is samba folder sharing dependent on
>   internet access?

No it isn't.  But you could configure your clients/servers in a way that would prevent them from working unless the Internet was up.

What you probably need to look at is things like DNS settings.  Is your server or workstations configured to use DNS servers outside of your network?  You might want to setup your to act as a caching DNS server and point your clients at that.

Answer (score 0):

I have now set up the caching DNS server. Now if the internet access goes down , then then samba server is still accessible.
However , if the internet access is down at the time of booting up the linux server , then access to the samba server is again not available.
The workstations are DHCP configured and their DNS settings are openDNS. I need to configure them to use the caching DNS server and recheck.

Comment: Am using bind as the caching nameserver by changing named.conf.options. as per http://www.zaphu.com/2007/09/10/ubuntu-dns-server-guide-bind-caching-name-server-setup/

will check how to set it up as a recursive resolver for the workstations .

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this is that clients can't resolve the IP address of the samba server when the internet connection is down. If this is the case, then I recommend to deploy a DNS server on the samba server. The DNS server should do the following:

- be a recursive resolver for your clients
- be a caching nameserver
- serve as an authoriative DNS server for your internal domain

If you have all this then clients should use this new service as their preferred DNS server.

Anyways, clients on an internal network shouldn't just reach OpenDNS directly, an internal DNS server is almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, but on opensuse. Here what I did:

In this file `/etc/resolv.conf`

- I had no ip set for the local DNS nameserver, wich in my case is the rooter itself.
- I had a few IP of internet DNS nameservers, that point out of my network, but not to my router, so I just added:

  ```
  nameserver 192.168.1.2
  ```

where 192.168.1.2 is my router IP and SAMBA works just great even when my internet connection is down.